# Convert list of strings to number of years

Tags: python, list, date, datetime

I have a list that looks like:

```
dates = ['0D', '1D', '1W', 2W', 2W1D', '3W', '1M', '1M2W', '2M', '2M2W', ..., '1Y', '1Y1M', '1Y1M2W',...]
```

I need to transform these into fraction in years based on 365 day year and 30 day month (ideally number of days per year and days in month can be changed).

```
days_in_year = 365
days_in_month = 30
dates_in_years = [...] # ? Fill code here
```

For example, `'0Y'` should be mapped to `0/365`, `'1W'` should be mapped to `7/365`, `'1M2W'` should be mapped to `(30+7*2)/365`, `'1Y1M2W'` should be mapped to `(365/365)+(30+7*2)/365`. These are just the formulas but output should be list of floats.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Transcending, 
Have you tried any code yet?
Add that too for better response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regex to extract, find out how many days total, divide by 365.

```
import re

dates = ['0D', '1D', '1W', '2W', '2W1D', '3W', '1M', '1M2W', '2M', '2M2W', '1Y', '1Y1M2W']

units = { "D":1, "W":7, "M":30, "Y":365 }    
def getY(dts):
    dts = re.findall(r"(\d+)(D|W|M|Y)",dts)
    sum = 0
    for n,unit in dts:
        sum+=float(n)*units[unit]
    return sum/365

print([getY(dt) for dt in dates])
```

variation using list comprehension and sum(), and generates a regex at runtime using keys in units:

```
import re

dates = ['0D', '1D', '1W', '2W', '2W1D', '3W', '1M', '1M2W', '2M', '2M2W', '1Y', '1Y1M2W']

units = { "D":1, "W":7, "M":30, "Y":365 }
def getY(dts):
    dts = re.findall(r"(\d+)({0})".format("|".join(units.keys())),dts)
    return sum([float(n)*units[unit] for n,unit in dts]) / 365

print([getY(dt) for dt in dates])
```

and a variation on the regex to use character classes if you know that units keys are all a single character, which is slightly faster:

```
dts = re.findall(r"(\d+)([{0}])".format("".join(units.keys())),dts)
```

Comment: Just add `import re` and this answer is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `dict()` to lookup the unit conversion, then walk thru date string pairwise(quantity, units):

```
dates = ['0D', '1D', '1W', '2W', '2W1D', '3W', '1M', '1M2W', '2M', '2M2W', '1Y', '1Y1M', '1Y1M2W']

units_in_days = {'D': 1,
                 'W': 7,
                 'M': 30,
                 'Y': 365,
                 }

for date in dates:
    total_days = 0
    for qty, unit in zip(date[::2], date[1::2]):
        total_days += int(qty) * units_in_days.get(unit, 0)
    print(f'{date}={total_days / units_in_days.get("Y")} years')
```

Output:

```
0D=0.0 years
1D=0.0027397260273972603 years
1W=0.019178082191780823 years
2W=0.038356164383561646 years
2W1D=0.0410958904109589 years
3W=0.057534246575342465 years
1M=0.0821917808219178 years
1M2W=0.12054794520547946 years
2M=0.1643835616438356 years
2M2W=0.20273972602739726 years
1Y=1.0 years
1Y1M=1.082191780821918 years
1Y1M2W=1.1205479452054794 years
```